# Change the color for each line

Tags: vb.net

I got a console application that draws line in a 3D CAD program. Now to make this more clear i want to change these lines in different colors.

My code read variables from a text-file and calculates data from it and then makes a lines from this calculated data.
This process gets repeated with every line in the text file wich contains data.

Now i want visual basic to change the color everytinme a new line is drawn, so i get different colored lines.

I tried using a For.. To.. Step method, but this didnt work. I also tried to use the variables from my text file( these are different so when a new line got read the RGB code will change) but this will geve me only a lot of blue colors.

Any suggestions?

EDit:

This is what i use to draw the curves, the RGB code has to cahnge everytime when a line with new data is made:

```
' Creating a Curve2d object by using the above defined points
                    objLineString = objLineStrings.AddByPoints(PointCount:=points, points:=dataArray)
                    objGeometricStyle = objLineString.Style
                    color = objGeometricStyle.LinearColor
                    objGeometricStyle.LinearColor = RGB(0,0,0)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that draws the lines ?

Comment: How does the CAD program read colors? Do you have to specify RGB values, or are there certain predefined color numbers you can just loop through?

Comment: If you change RGB(0, 0, 0) o RGB(255, 0, 0), does it draw a red line ?

Comment: The CAD program is called Solid Edge. I added some code where i draw a line string, and then change the style of that line into an color with RGB code.

Comment: Yes it does draw a red line if i set taht RGB code to a color. But i want to have that number changed every line. My program already has a  loop where it reads all the data of the first textline, calculates points and then draws a line. So somehow the RGB code has to change every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
Dim rand As New Random() ' Used to generate random numbers
Dim colors(100) as Integer

' Create the colors
For i as Integer = 0 to 100 Step 1
    colors(i) = RGB(rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256))
Next

For i As Integer = 0 To 100 Step 1 ' Adjust to your needs
    ' Creating a Curve2d object by using the above defined points
    objLineString = objLineStrings.AddByPoints(PointCount:=points, points:=dataArray)
    objGeometricStyle = objLineString.Style
    color = objGeometricStyle.LinearColor
    objGeometricStyle.LinearColor = colors(i Mod 100) ' Mod returns the remainder of i / 100, so it's always less than 100.
Next
```

This won't always give you "pretty" colors, but they'll be different for each line. If you want control over the generated colors, you could set up an array of predefined colors and use these in your iteration.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but the problem is( my fault) I got three ways to make a line. And those three need to be the same color, now those got different ones. and that a different color for the new read data. And also it goes very slow to choose a color.

Comment: Well then create a set of colors, store them in an array, and loop through the array. See my edit.